# Building sqlite3mc amalgamation fails with ‘_mm_aesimc_si128’: target specific option mismatch - Even with -march=native

Tags: c++, c, makefile, intel, intrinsics

I'm trying to build this project: https://github.com/utelle/SQLite3MultipleCiphers
Specifically the amalgamation files found at: https://github.com/utelle/SQLite3MultipleCiphers/releases/tag/v1.2.5

I'm getting this error from the `_mm_aesimc_si128` function:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/wmmintrin.
h:77: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_aesimc_si128’: target specific option mismatch
In file included from ../sqlite3mc/sqlite3mc_amalgamation.c:250494:
../sqlite3mc/sqlite3mc_amalgamation.c: In function ‘aesGenKeyDecrypt’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/wmmintrin.h:77:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘_mm_aesimc_si128’: target specific option mismatch
   77 | _mm_aesimc_si128 (__m128i __X)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../sqlite3mc/sqlite3mc_amalgamation.c:250589:26: note: called from here
```

I understand from other questions that my CPU needs to support these intrinsic functions and that I need to pass in compiler flags to enable them. I *think* I need AES and SSE4.2 for this, since the Makefile.am from the Github code has `-msse4.2 -maes` for x86.

I'm using QtCreator and qmake because I'm trying to integrate this into a existing Qt project, but I'm just trying to get it to work with a new project for now.

This is my .pro file, I'm passing in the `-march=native` flag (I also tried `-msse4.2 -maes` with the same results):

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle qt debug_and_release

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        sqlite3mc_amalgamation.c

HEADERS += \
    sqlite3.h \
    sqlite3ext.h \
    sqlite3mc_amalgamation.h

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -march=native
```

Checking the enabled flags for my architecture, and searching for aes and sse gives me:

```
g++ -Q --help=target -march=native | egrep "(msse)|(maes)"

-maes                               [enabled]
-msse                               [enabled]
-msse2                              [enabled]
-msse2avx                           [disabled]
-msse3                              [enabled]
-msse4                              [enabled]
-msse4.1                            [enabled]
-msse4.2                            [enabled]
-msse4a                             [disabled]
-msse5                              
-msseregparm                        [disabled]
```

Checking my CPU's available extensions and searching for sse and aes:

```
lscpu | egrep "(sse)|(aes)"
Flags: sse sse2 ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 aes <many other flags>
```

So SSE4.2 and AES are both enabled by `-march=native` and are supported by my CPU, but I'm still getting the error.

What can I do to get past this error (and hopefully get the whole thing to build)?

Comment: That's something you should probably take to their issue tracker. The Github repository you linked provides some build instructions, make sure you go through them before creating an issue: https://utelle.github.io/SQLite3MultipleCiphers/docs/installation/install_overview/

Comment: @asynts I just used the wrong compiler option. It's a C file built with gcc, not g++, so I needed QMAKE_CFLAGS not QMAKE_CXXFLAGS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the amalgamation file is a C file it should be:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -march=native
```

not

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -march=native
```

Additionally, sqlite3mc uses pthread and ldl so these libraries must be linked:

```
LIBS += -pthread -ldl
```

After making these changes it builds successfully.